# SugarCRM Save button on Accounts module

Tags: php, html, ajax, sugarcrm

I have 2 instances of SugarCRM that I tested this on but while the "Save" button works for one instance it fails on another. These seems to be the lines of codes that causes the problem:

```
<div class="action_buttons">
<input title="Save" accesskey="a" class="button primary" onclick="var _form = document.getElementById('EditView'); _form.action.value='Save'; if(check_form('EditView'))SUGAR.ajaxUI.submitForm(_form);return false;" type="submit" name="button" value="Save" id="SAVE_HEADER">
```

I tracked it down using Chrome Developer tool and some basic testing revealed it will save when changing 'EditView' to any other value (it can literally be anything such as 'q' or 'AditView', etc).

```
if(check_form('EditView'))
```

Can anyone help solve this?

Comment: Tested *what* on exactly? The Save button itself? Unaltered, there should be no issue there. Are these two instances two different versions of SugarCRM? If so, what versions? What other differences are there between the two instances?

Comment: I tested this on Google Chrome and neither the Save or the "Save and Continue" button processes the request to save any changes. However, the other CRM instance which practically has the same changes, does. They are the same (SugarCRM CE 6.5.16). Another weird thing is that when I tested this on Internet Explorer is that the save button works on both instances. I tried deleting the caches in the crm, did "Quick Repair and Rebuild", etc. but it didn't change anything.

Comment: "*practically* has the same changes" if these systems were 100% literal clones, you wouldn't have this issue. Something is different and it's affecting the Account Edit View, or edit view metadata, or possibly the SAVE button itself. Dig into /custom/modules/Accounts and /custom/include and see what's different in those systems.

Comment: Will do. Upon further investigation, tracking the "Event Listeners" such as 'mouse click' shows this additional line in index.php of the problematic crm instance:                                                                          <script>(function() {with (this[2]) {with (this[1]) {with (this[0]) {return function(event) {this.form.action.value='Save';if(check_form('EditView')){sendAndRedirect('EditView', 'Saving Accounts...', '?action=ajaxui#ajaxUILoc=index.php%3Faction%3DEditView%26module%3DAccounts%26record%3D3272d89f-2378-ba40-157d-4f50e0335c3c%26offset%3D48')...

Comment: You're right! I've made some modifications to the custom/modules/Accounts/metadata and now it's been causing me problems that I'm just encountering. Thanks a lot for your help Matthew! I'll try to post info after further testing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I finally tracked down the issue when I was rebuilding the EditView layout in Studio. A "radio type" of button was flagged as 'required', however, if the user leaves or set it to "None" (the default value), it doesn't alert the user that they should be changing it to any valid options.

So, unlike text fields, it doesn't indicate any issue except that it won't save when clicking the Save button. Even more, unlike the text field, where if it requires a value it will highlight the tab where it resides in red, radio type fields do not. I replicated this behavior on the other crm instance. So to fix this, I went to Studio and just unchecked the "Required" flag on all my 'radio' type fields.

I guess it also has something to do with the web browser being used. My testing is limited to Internet Explorer v9 and Google Chrome v34 but if anyone wants to test this behavior on other browsers, that would be great.